# Media recovery and rooting my phone

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, 8.0-oreo

I have an LG G6 (**LG-H870**) with **android oreo 8.0.0**, **kernel version 3.18.71**
I want to root in mainly to recover a couple videos I've deleted.
If there is a way to recover the videos without root that would be great, if not then I need some help rooting my device because I've never done it before.
The videos I've deleted were locked and I have "*permanantly delete*d" them as they don't go in the trash.

I've found this : https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g6/development/tool-tool-one-driversunlocktwrpfactory-t3674088

Also, I know that rooting my phone voids my warranty so I was wondering if there was a way to **unroot my phone in order to get back my warranty** after I'm done recovering my videos/photos?

Basically...
**Is there a way to recover deleted videos/images without rooting my device and if not then how do I safely root it?**

Comment: you can't root without data loss, because unlocking the bootloader will factory reset. there might be a small chance to root without unlocking via rooting app. But your phone is encrypted, it is hard to recover deleted files. However, you can try to get a copy of your phone with QPST+HDDRawCopy and see if userdata is already decrypted (only then you can run tools like photorec on the disk image) https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178